# How to commit another object in a property of an object in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

As the title says.

Here are the codes.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime, func, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy.exc
from sqlalchemy import event
from settings import DB_HOST

def return_a_scoped_session():
    engine = create_engine(DB_HOST)
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    db_session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    return db_session()

Base = declarative_base()


class MyClass(Base):
    """Doc string for MyClass"""
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    file_name = Column(String(512), nullable=True)


class Aria2Jobs(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nh_downloading_jobs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    file_name = Column(String(512), nullable=True)
    is_verified = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=True)

    def check_if_verified(self):
        if self.is_verified:
            # create an instance
            a_job= MyClass(file_name=self.file_name)
            _session = return_a_scoped_session()
            _session.add(a_job)
            _session.commit()
            _session.close()

# event
@event.listens_for(Aria2Jobs.is_verified, 'set')
def send_to_jsonpyes_jobs(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.check_if_verified()

# error is when I set a property of an object (this property will trigger an event 'set' and the event will try to commit a session.

session = return_a_scoped_session()
row = session.query(Aria2Jobs).first()
row.is_verified = True
session.add(row)

# the error came out
# 
# sqlalchemy.exc.invalidrequesterror object is already attached to session
session.commit()

# How to commit another object in a property of an object?
```

How to commit another object in a property of an object in sqlalchemy?

As you can see, when I tried `session.add(row)`,

error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.invalidrequesterror object is already attached to session
```

I don't know which session the `row` is attached to.
I want to run the function `check_if_verified`

-- latest error --

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Aria2Jobs at 0x7fad3a635050>' is already attached to session '1' (this is
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy [explicitly recommends against](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it) allowing model classes to commit sessions. Instead of asking "how can I do this particular thing", you may find it more helpful to tell us the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you. I change the way of programming using SQLAlchemy. And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `session.add(row)`. Becouse you used `session.query` the `row` object is already in your session. 
To save the data is enough to run `session.commit` function

Answer (score 0):

You're using `scoped_session` incorrectly. What's happening here is each time you call `return_a_scoped_session()` it's returning a *new* session, with a completely new engine. `row` is being added to a different session somewhere else. (In fact, the code you posted doesn't even show the other places it's being added; I can't reproduce your error with the code you posted.) The solution is to fix your `scoped_session`:

```
engine = create_engine(DB_HOST)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def return_a_scoped_session():
    return Session()
```